# For $a,b$ in a group $G$, if $|a|=36$ and $\langle a^{21}\rangle =\langle b^{10}\rangle$, what is $|\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Attempt: I previously had to show that the only possible values for $|b|$ are $24$ and $120$. But I don't know how that's supposed to help.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following steps:

1. $H=\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle$ is a cyclic group.
2. $|H|$ divides $|a|$ and $|b|$, in other words $|H|$ divides $gcd(36,120)=12$.
3. Show that $|a^{21}|=12$ and $a^{21}$ is a power of $b$.
4. Conclude that $|H|=12$.